# Delphi Firemonkey: Creating Cube on a 3D viewport at runtime, from a different unit

Tags: delphi, 3d, firemonkey

I'm designing 3D minesweeper. I would like to create a class to generate the 3D Cube (which will be composed of multiple TCubes, in a cube shape), which will be in a seperate class and unit to the 3D Viewport. I need to make the Cube to runtime. I am using a Multidimensional array (Array of Array of Array of TCube). This is the code I currently have which attempts to do so

Main Unit:

```
unit mineMainForm;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Rtti, System.Classes,
  System.Variants, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Types3D,
  FMX.Objects3D, mineControl;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm3D)
    procedure Form3DCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;
  Controller : TController;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm2.Form3DCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Controller.create(Form2,10);
end;

end.
```

Unit in which the issue lies:

```
unit mineControl;

interface

uses
 FMX.Forms, FMX.Objects3D, sysutils;

Type
 tController = class
   private
     cubeArray : Array[1..10,1..10,1..10]  of TCube;
   public
    constructor create(Form : TForm3D; cubeCount :integer);
 end;

implementation

{ tController }

constructor tController.create(Form: TForm3D; cubeCount: integer); //cubeCount Max 10, min 1
var
  x, y, z : Integer;
begin
for x := 1 to cubeCount do
 begin
  for y := 1 to cubeCount do
   begin
    for z := 1 to cubeCount do
     begin
       CubeArray[x,y,z] := TCube.Create(Form);
        With CubeArray[x,y,z] do
         begin
           Visible := True;
           Position.X := 0;
           Position.Y := 0;
           Position.Z := 0;
           Parent := Form;
         end;
        end;
    end;
   end;
 end;

end.
```

I am receiving an Access violation error where I try to run the create using "mineField" as the AOwner. How could I fix this so it works, or if that would not work, how would I do it?

I am quite new to coding (1 1/2 years of high school) and would appreciate if you assume I know quite little. Thanks a lot.

Error: "Access Violation at address 00A0CFBB in module 'mine3D_p.exe'. Write of Address 00000008"

Comment: TCube.Create( minefield ) ;o)

Comment: Thanks, I will edit that, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please paste the error message into your question?

Comment: How did you declare CubeArray? Maybe you miss the starting array index and you have to go from 0 to CubeCount-1

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, added them to the question (Declaration and error)

Comment: add a stack of the error by using MadExcept or any other similar tool.

Comment: Show the calling code, the code that calls `TFieldControl.Create`. In fact, show a complete program the demonstrates the fault. Read this: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Issue is you are calling

```
Controller.create(Form2,10);
```

instead of

```
Controller := TController.create(Form2,10);
```